# Client side translation of javascript dates with angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters, angular-translate

I'm using AngularJS. Let's say I have a date 16th August 2015, and I want to format it on the screen with the format 'dd MMM yyy', so that is displays `16 Aug 2015`.

That's easy using the date filter.

Now, I want to switch language on the fly to Spanish, so that the text now says `16 Ago 2015`

How can I do this? I have been using angular-translate but I can't see how to hook it in with the date filter. Do I have to write my own directive which renders the day, month and year separately so that I can apply the angular-translate directive to the month part?

Comment: Without ever having tried anything remotely similar, I would think changing the locale would be the way to go.

Comment: I don't think core angular i18n funcionality supports locale change on the fly.

Comment: We're talking JavaScript. Does Angular support JavaScript? XD

Comment: I don't follow... when you say 'changing the locale', are you referring to angular's locale support?

Comment: No. I'm talking about changing the locale of your Date object.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
app.filter('dateLocalized', [function(){
    return function(date, lang){
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = {
            en: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
            es: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sept', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dic']
        }[lang][date.getMonth()];
        return [day, month, year].join(' ');
    };
}]);
```

In html:

```
<div ng-bind="date | dateLocalized: lang"></div>
```

`lang` will be `en` or `es`.

Comment: This isn't what I did in the end, but it made me realise that I don't have to be bound to either angular-translate for the translating, or the angular date filter for the display formatting... I will put my own solution as a separate answer

Answer (score 1):

[Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/api/Date/setLocale) lets you set the locale on the fly:

`date.setLocale('es')`

Once you set the locale, it is easy enough to call `date.toLocaleString()`.

Answer (score 0):

you should  write  prototype like this .

> Date.prototype.yyyymmdd = function() {
>
> ```
>         var yyyy = this.getFullYear().toString();
>
>         var mm = (this.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
>         var dd  = this.getDate().toString();
>
>         return yyyy +"-"+ (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) +"-"+ (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]); // padding
>
>        };
> ```

here
when you call

> var dt = new Date();
>
> dt.yyyymmdd();

it will give you   year month  day format  here in the part of month your can change whatever you want .

Good luck .

Answer (score 0):

I took the answer from karaxuna, but made a few adjustments. Firstly, I used a directive rather than a filter although I don't see why a filter would not work. However, in my case there were other complexities which I didn't want to pollute the question with, that made me want the additional power that directives can give.

The second difference is that I did not implement my own formatting / language support - I used momentJs, which does both out of the box.

Here's a cut-down snippet of the code (in Typescript):

```
interface ValueformatterScope extends ng.IScope {
    value: string;
    dataType: string;
    i18nService: I18nService;
}

class ValueFormatter {
    constructor( i18nService: I18nService ) {
        return {
            restrict: 'AC',       // Only apply on an attribute or class
            scope: {
                value: '=ngModel',  // The two-way data bound value that is returned by the directive
                dataType: '=dataType',
            },
            link: (scope: ValueformatterScope, element: JQuery) => {

                function render() {
                    var formattedText: string;

                    if (scope.value == null || scope.value === '') {
                        formattedText = "";
                    }
                    else if (scope.value == '-') {
                        formattedText = '-';
                    }

                    else if (scope.dataType == 'DATE') {
                        //dates should be shown in GMT (i.e., not converted to local timezone from DB)
                        var dateUtc = Util.getUtcDate(scope.value);
                        formattedText = moment(dateUtc).format(i18nService.locale.dateFormat);
                    }

                    element.text(formattedText);
                }

                scope.i18nService = i18nService;

                scope.$watch("i18nService.locale", () => {
                    render();
                });

                scope.$watch('value', () => {
                    render();
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When the user switches locale, I just call `moment.locale(newLocale)`, and then update the `i18nService.locale` value, which triggers the `$watch`